# SQL - Need Results in one Table

Tags: sql-server, adventureworks

I am trying to complete the following question for a homework assignment, but have been at it for hours, and could use some help. The result set should be one table with 260 records, but the results I get are in two different tables. I know I am close, but what am I missing?

4) Display all customers and any orders that contains the word LOCK in their name. Hint using a LIKE statement. This query is similar to the bottom of page 326 and top of page 327.

a) First write the query to select orders with the word LOCK in their name. Using the inner join for Production.Product table and the salesorderdetail and the salesorderheader. Should get 260 records in your result set. Show the product.name and customerid

```
SELECT 
    Product.Name
FROM 
    Production.Product
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail ON Product.ProductID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%lock%'

SELECT
    SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID
FROM 
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
```

Comment: Why do you have two `SELECT` statements? Just write `SELECT Product.Name, SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID FROM` then do your joins and add a `WHERE` condition with the `LIKE` operator you already wrote.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can join more than 2 tables

```
SELECT 
    SalesOrderHeader.CustomerID, Product.Name
FROM
    Production.Product
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderDetail ON Product.ProductID = SalesOrderDetail.ProductID
INNER JOIN
    Sales.SalesOrderHeader ON SalesOrderHeader.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
WHERE
    Name LIKE '%lock%'
```